# Using Graphics to Draw Image directly onto Screen in VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, graphics

I'm trying to draw an image directly onto the desktop in VB.NET.

I've used this following code to use graphics to draw the `.PNG` image onto the form with a given location without the need of a `PictureBox`, but what I require that the image be drawn onto the screen itself (desktop), not the form.

The code I currently posses is used to draw the image onto the form at a specific location at the Form's `Paint` event, and it works well. (From: [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/advanced/how-to-draw-an-existing-bitmap-to-the-screen?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)).

```
Dim bitmap As New Bitmap("Sunset.png")
e.Graphics.DrawImage(bitmap, 1160, 1110)
```

This sample draws the image onto the form, but I would like the image to be drawn on the desktop itself, not the form.

I've found this example which draws a rectangle with text onto the screen itself (Not the Form!), but I haven't figured out how to get it to work with drawing a picture.

```
Public Class Form1

    Dim Test As String = "Drawing text onto the screen"
    Dim stringFont As New Font("Arial", 24, FontStyle.Bold)
    Dim string_format As New StringFormat()

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        string_format.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center
        string_format.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Near

        Timer1.Interval = 1000
        Timer1.Start()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        Dim rect As Rectangle = New Rectangle(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width / 2, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height / 2, 300, 300)
        rect.Inflate(2, 2)
        Using g As Graphics = Graphics.FromHwnd(IntPtr.Zero)
            Using lgb As New Drawing2D.LinearGradientBrush(rect, Color.Red, Color.Orange, 90, True)
                g.FillRectangle(lgb, rect)
                g.DrawString(Test, stringFont, Brushes.Black, rect, string_format)
            End Using
        End Using
    End Sub

End Class
```

How can I use Graphics to draw an image directly onto the screen (Not onto the form)?

Comment: Guessing Graphics.DrawImage() in your Timer1_Tick event isn't doing what your after?

Comment: The second example draws a rectangle with some text, but I want to replace the rectangle with the text with an image instead. @Hursey

Comment: `g.DrawImage(bitmap, 1160, 1110)`. Expect a not so happy Desktop (and pretty *slow response*) (and lack of persistence) (probably unhappy users).

Comment: It's probably better to position a Window and draw the Image using its own generated Graphics object.